# How can I reset a USB device using command line utilities?

Tags: raspbian

I need to find and modify one line from the output of `lsusb`

```
pi@junior ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04fc:05d8 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd Wireless keyboard/mouse
```

So, grep to search:

```
pi@junior ~ $ lsusb | grep 12d1:1506
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

Now I need to modifiy the grep statement or pipe it into something else to get the following value:

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/009
```

Which I then need to pass into:

```
/usr/sbin/usbreset /dev/bus/usb/001/009
```

If I was coding, I would use a Regex:

```
Bus (\d{3}) Device (\d{3}).*15d1:1506.*
```

Replace with

```
/dev/bus/usb/\1/\2
```

Any idea how I can do this in a script?
I also need to know how to store that in a variable to be passed to `usbreset` as a parameter.

Comment: `sed` is your friend. You can [use this page](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt) or search for "sed examples". Generally you just want a small shell script that does a few things, including passing it to usbreset. Hopefully someone will give you a more specific example, but these are the building blocks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use grep for this issue. lsusb can output with -d parameter to get information about given usb vendor:id number. (lsusb -d )

So your command should like this.

```
$(lsusb -d 12d1:1506 | awk -F '[ :]'  '{ print "/dev/bus/usb/"$2"/"$4 }' | xargs -I {} echo "./usbreset {}")
```

Save it with nano, chmod +x and you can invoke it with sudo.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I used `sed`
It turned out the `usbreset` wasn't the command for the job, I need to use a file called `authorized` which you echo 0 and then 1 to.

```
echo "Searching for $1"
devPath=`lsusb | grep $1 | sed -r 's/Bus ([0-9]{3}) Device ([0-9]{3}).*/bus\/usb\/\1\/\2/g;'`
echo "Found $1 @ $devPath"
echo "Searching for sysPath"
for sysPath in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*; do
    echo "$sysPath/uevent"
    devName=`cat "$sysPath/uevent" | grep $devPath`
    #echo devName=$devName
    if [ ! -z $devName ] 
    then
        break
    fi
done
if [ ! -z  $devName ] 
then
    echo "Found $1 @ $sysPath, Resetting"
    echo "echo 0 > $sysPath/authorized"
    echo 0 > $sysPath/authorized
    echo "echo 1 > $sysPath/authorized"
    echo 1 > $sysPath/authorized
else
    echo "Could not find $1"
fi
```

This allowed me to use familiar regex notation

Answer (score 1):

I used awk.
`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter`

`lsusb | awk -F '[ :]' ' /Ralink/ { print "/dev/bus/usb/"$2"/"$4 } '`

`/dev/bus/usb/001/002`

If you wanted to use that with usbreset, then you could do this

`# usbreset $(lsusb | awk -F '[ :]' ' /12d1:1506/ | { print "/dev/bus/usb/"$2"/"$4 }')`

Theoretically...I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which does not depend on awk, but only on simpler text processing utilities:

```
lsusb -d 12d1:1506 | tr ':' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2,4 | xargs printf "/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s" | xargs usbreset
```

Answer (score 0):

one command:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/usbreset $(ls /dev/bus/usb/001/$( lsusb | grep 12d1:1506 | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | cut -c-3))
```

I also understand you are using this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/645/how-do-you-reset-a-usb-device-from-the-command-line

Comment: You might want to explain what that command does, even in minor detail, just to make your answer more useful.