# Reset Wi-Fi dongle

Tags: wifi, networking, failure, reset

I too ran into problems with USB Wi-Fi dongle on RPi. After being on for roughly a day RPi loses Wi-Fi link. If I run `ping` to the gateway command fails with `"Destination host not reachable"` message. People seem to solve problem by issuing `ifdown wlan0` followed by `ifup wlan0`. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Only way I can get connection back is to physically unplug USB dongle and plug it again. How can I imitate physical reset with console commands as close as possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset a USB device using command line utilities?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9289/how-can-i-reset-a-usb-device-using-command-line-utilities)

Comment: You can remove the modules that manage the device from the kernel, reinsert them, and restart the relevant services (wpa_supplicant, NetworkManager etc.).

Comment: This turned out to help only temporarily. Even physically reseating USB dongle helps only for 3-4 minutes and then Wi Fi signal disappears again. I figured out best solution is to add a cron job to periodically ping gateway and reset Pi if no response is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a power management setting for your wireless needs to be updated. Run `iwconfig` and look for a line like this:

`Power Management:off`

If you see "on" instead of "off" you will need to update doing the following:

Type at the command line: `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Insert this text anywhere: `wireless-power off`

Save the doc, close, and then at the command line type: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Check `iwconfig` output again to make sure the power management setting took.

Answer (score 1):

What type of dongle is it?
there's a tweak to turn off power management on Realtek 8192CU Based Wifi Modules

https://gist.github.com/broo0ose/df05a5b56ccd40f60fef

Comment: I'm using ASUS N10 which is based on RTL8192SU. But I figured out resetting Pi would be the best option.